# How to get sub directory in android?

Tags: android

My code is for renaming files in a folder on the SD card, however, it doesn't rename files in sub folders present in the same folder.

here is my approach, i added this line -

```
ExplorerDBOperation(listFile[i]);
```

but the error i get is - "The method ExplorerDBOperation(File) is undefined for the type Hide.ExplorerDBOperation" how do i call my method again? this is in an AsyncTask

```
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        File listFile[] = myDirectory.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    ExplorerDBOperation(listFile[i]);
                } else {
                    String fPath = listFile[i].getPath();

                    for (String ext : TARGET_EXTENSIONS) {
                        fPath = fPath.replace("." + ext,
                                "a6d5dx" + ext);
                    }

                    listFile[i].renameTo(new File(fPath));
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**FULL CODE**

```
// getting SDcard root path
File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + "/SecuDrive/");
public static final String[] TARGET_EXTENSIONS = {  "exe", "apk", "tar", "img", "iso" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hide);
    // at the end of oncreate
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new ExplorerDBOperation().execute();
        }
    }, 300);
}

class ExplorerDBOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Boolean, Boolean> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Hide.this, "Please wait",
                "Processing..");
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        File listFile[] = myDirectory.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    ExplorerDBOperation(listFile[i]);
                } else {
                    String fPath = listFile[i].getPath();

                    for (String ext : TARGET_EXTENSIONS) {
                        fPath = fPath.replace("." + ext,
                                "a6d5dx" + ext);
                    }

                    listFile[i].renameTo(new File(fPath));
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  @Override
  protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
     renameInDir(myDirectory);
     return true;
  }

  private void renameInDir(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                renameInDir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                String fPath = listFile[i].getPath();

                for (String ext : TARGET_EXTENSIONS) {
                    fPath = fPath.replace("." + ext,
                            "a6d56fdgdg34fgh45u745ju672fdx" + ext);
                }

                listFile[i].renameTo(new File(fPath));
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: renameInDir(listFile[i]);   just this line?

Comment: @abbie aha, note that you need to add this method in your async task